# What do these numbers mean in regard to PCI Configuration Space

Tags: pci

Wikipedia provides this picture to add to their explanation:

[image]

What do the numbers on the right indicate or represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those numbers to the right are just Hexadecimal offsets.  They can also be represented by 0x00, 0x1C and so on.  So from the image the Device ID and Vendor ID are found in the first 4 bytes. Remember that a byte is 8bits so a 16bit Device ID is two bytes.

Hex is a base 16 numbering system. 
Hex numbering is as follows
00,
01,
02,
03,
04,
05,
06,
07,
08,
09,
0A,
0B,
0C,
0D,
0E,
0F,
10,

Comment: I was under the impression that Hex numbering didn't include some of the values listed on that image.

Comment: The numbers on the right are all valid Hex numbers.  Which ones do you think are not included?

Comment: They all have "h" in them and generally I had not seen them in said offset form.  I was under the impression they had to be represented with an "x" and usually started with 0. 0xAF etc

Comment: The "x" is the most common way to represent hex such as 0xAF as you said.  The "0x" indicates Hex, however a lesser used method is to also unclude an "h" at the end of the number.  So "0xAF" and "AFh" are the same number.

Comment: Could you provide me any documentation on that ?

Comment: Sure this is quoted from a Wikipedia article "To avoid confusion with decimal, octal or other numbering systems, hexadecimal numbers are sometimes written with a "h" after the number. For example, 63h means 63 hexadecimal" [Article](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal_numeral_system)

Comment: No Problem, glad I could help